# MS Access: Combo Box - Unselect items to return to original state

Tags: ms-access

I am aware this is a simple question, but I can't seem to find the solution anywhere online.

I have a combobox that works as a filter for a subform. The combobox is populated by a simple select query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT Report.Date FROM Report
```

The combo box filters the subform for the date selected by the user and works in unison with other filter criteria on my form.

The default selection of my combo box is null (blank), so therefore all dates in the report are selected, which is what I want.

However if I select a date from the populated list the only way to get back to the default view is by highlighting the date selected, deleting this and pressing enter which will remove the filter. Some of the end users of this will not know that this is what is needed as they will not be familiar with Access.

Is there a way to include an option in the combobox to reset it to null, so that the date filter will be removed?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is code that sets filter for subform? At end of procedure: `Me.comboboxname = Null`.

Comment: I had though of that, but then that will remove the filter just applied by the user the way my code is working. I just thought there would be a way to include an option in the combo box that resets it?

Comment: Are you using a dynamic parameterized query as form RecordSource? I never use them. I use VBA to build and apply filter criteria to form or report. Edit question to show form RecordSource or code. Combobox RowSource could be a UNION query that adds an empty row to the list.

Comment: I'm using the above code 'SELECT DISTINCT Report.Date FROM Report' in the 'Row Source' option within the 'data' tab of the properties for the combo box. The code that then applies the filters only works off the selected value in the combo box. The filters etc work fine, I was just looking for a way to remove the filters from the combo box without using a button etc. I didn't think of using union to add in a different option, I'll do that now thank you

Comment: Why would programmatically setting combobox to Null change applied filter?